# NOTE: Invalid numeric data, DateFrom='2018-01-11 18:30:00.000' , at line 85 column 20. DatePart option used to remove time from date

Tags: sas, dataset

```
Data A_DateFrom;  
set Agent_Hist; 
DateFrom1=Datepart(DateFrom);
Format DateFrom1 date9.;
run;
```

#### In output DateFrom1 column is blank while running this code in SAS. It is giving some warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First run `proc contents` to see what is the type of `DateFrom`:

```
proc contents data=Agent_Hist;
run;
```

I suspect it may be character. In that case first use `input()` function:

```
data test;
  DateFrom='2018-01-11 18:30:00.000';
  DateFrom1 = input(DateFrom, yymmdd10.);
  format DateFrom1 date11.;
run;
```